# Jison: Conflict in grammar when if-else and for statements ara combined

Tags: javascript, parsing, if-statement, for-loop, jison

I want to make a parser for a subset of JavaScript language with jison and I have some problems.

At first I had this definition for nonterminal `stmt` and it works:

```
stmt
    : FOR LPAREN varlist_decl SEMICOLON expr SEMICOLON expr RPAREN stmt
        {$$ = ['for ('].concat($3, ['; '], $5, ['; '], $7, [') '], $9)}
    | varlist_decl 
        {$$ = $1}
    | expr
        {$$ = $1}
    | LBRACE stmts RBRACE
        {$$ = ['{', 0, 1].concat($2, [0, -1, '}'])}
    ;
```

After, I added the following rules in `stmt`:

```
    : IF LPAREN expr RPAREN stmt
        {$$ = ['if ('].concat($3, [') '], $5)}
    | IF LPAREN expr RPAREN stmt ELSE stmt
        {$$ = ['if ('].concat($3, [') '], $5, [0, 'else '], $7)}
```

This grammar is ambiguous and conflict appears. So I followed these pattern to solve the dangling else ambiguity:

```
stmt
    : IF LPAREN expr RPAREN stmt
    | IF LPAREN expr RPAREN stmt ELSE stmt
    | other_stmt
    ;
```

It must be transformed into:
    stmt
        : closed_stmt
        | non_closed_stmt
        ;

```
closed_stmt
    : IF LPAREN expr RPAREN closed_stmt ELSE closed_stmt
    | other_stmt
    ;

non_closed_stmt
    : IF LPAREN expr RPAREN stmt
    | IF LPAREN expr RPAREN closed_stmt ELSE non_closed_stmt
    ;
```

This is current part of my grammar:

```
stmt
    : closed_stmt
        {$$ = $1}
    | non_closed_stmt
        {$$ = $1}
    ;

closed_stmt
    : IF LPAREN expr RPAREN closed_stmt ELSE closed_stmt
        {$$ = ['if ('].concat($3, [') '], $5, [0, 'else '], $7)}
    | FOR LPAREN varlist_decl SEMICOLON expr SEMICOLON expr RPAREN stmt
        {$$ = ['for ('].concat($3, ['; '], $5, ['; '], $7, [') '], $9)}
    | varlist_decl 
        {$$ = $1}
    | expr
        {$$ = $1}
    | LBRACE stmts RBRACE
        {$$ = ['{', 0, 1].concat($2, [0, -1, '}'])}
    ;

non_closed_stmt
    : IF LPAREN expr RPAREN stmt
        {$$ = ['if ('].concat($3, [') '], $5)}
    | IF LPAREN expr RPAREN closed_stmt ELSE non_closed_stmt
        {$$ = ['if ('].concat($3, [') '], $5, [0, 'else '], $7)}
    ;
```

and this part only work when I comment the `for-statement` rule.

How do you fix it?

Here is my full code repository: https://github.com/xgbuils/if-for-grammar-issue

Answer (score 1):

You need closed and non-closed forms of the `for` statement; it cannot just end with `stmt`. So you put a closed form ending with `closed_stmt` in the `closed_stmt` rules, and a non-closed form ending with `non_closed_stmt` in the `non_closed_stmt` rules.

That's because

```
for (x=0;x<3;++x) if (x==2) do_something();
```

is just as non-closed as

```
if (x==2) do_something();
```

in the sense that it will absorb a following `else` token. The closedness of the `if` statement is not altered by preceding it with one (or more) `for` headers.